# How to restart postgresql service in windows 10 when updating pg_hba.config

Tags: postgresql

How do I restart the PostgreSQL service in Windows 10 when updating pg_hba.config? What are the steps to allow remote connections to a psql database?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need to restart the service to activate changes done to `pg_hba.conf`.

All you need to do is to *reload* the configuration.

### Reload using a SQL statement

You can re-load all configuration files using a SQL statement, e.g. from within `psql` - but any SQL client will do:

```
select pg_reload_conf();
```

You must log-in to Postgres as a database super user (typically `postgres`).

### Reload using `pg_ctl`

[`pg_ctl`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-ctl.html) can be used to signal a reload to the server

```
pg_ctl reload -D \path\to\datadirectory
```

The data directory is the one [you specified](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/creating-cluster.html) during installation. If you don't know where the data directory is, use a SQL client and run `show data_directory;` to find out.

### Restart the Windows service

If you do want to restart the service completely then do this as you would with any other Windows service [through the control panel](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4499-services-start-stop-disable-windows-10-a.html). Alternatively you can do that [on the command line](https://superuser.com/q/301765)